# Why starman / plackup don't recommend option -r

Tags: perl, starman

I want to start starman with option -r to upgrades source code without to restart server.

```
starman --workers 32 --port 8080 -r mytest.psgi 
!!
!! Using restarter with -r or -R options is known to cause issues with process supervisor
!! such as start_server, and it is STRONGLY discouraged to use with Starman. You have been warned.
!!
Watching ./lib mytest.psgi for file updates.
2014/11/11-20:28:00 Starman::Server (type Net::Server::PreFork) starting! pid(28380)
Resolved [*]:8080 to [0.0.0.0]:8080, IPv4
Binding to TCP port 8080 on host 0.0.0.0 with IPv4
Setting gid to "1000 1000 24 25 27 29 30 44 46 103 104 107 108 900 1000"
^C2014/11/11-20:28:01 Server closing!
```

My question is what is the reason for the follwing statement : "STRONGLY discouraged to use with Starman" . Can I use option -r starmann in production ?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/starman#RELOADING-THE-APPLICATION): "These options will make a separate directory watcher process, and makes your life difficult if you want to combine with other process daemon tools such as `Server::Starter`." The recommended way: "If you want to preload the app and do graceful restarts by reloading the code changes, you're recommended to use `Server::Starter`, configured to send `QUIT` signal when superdaemon received `HUP` [...]"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: that should probably be an answer?

Comment: Also: "Sending `HUP` signal to the master process will restart all the workers gracefully (meaning the currently running requests will shut down once the request is complete), and by default, the workers will pick up the code changes you make by reloading the application."

Comment: @ysth I haven't used starman enough to be able to elaborate on what I quoted in the docs; I could well be missing something. I'll wait a while and make it an answer if nobody has a better one.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I think it's been a while and nobody else has posted an answer.  I've only just discovered starman so I still trying to understand the answer.